# Chef generate cookbook

Tags: linux, chef-infra, ubuntu-14.04, chef-recipe

I am having issue when creating a cookbook, like shown below:

What could this be related to? I have the `chef-dk` installed. I am new to chef, so please do not hesitate if you need more information about my environment.

```
root@chef-work:/home/ubuntu/chef-repo/cookbooks# chef generate cookbook learn_chef_apache2
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_PAPER = "nb_NO.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Can't open generate: No such file or directory.
Can't open cookbook: No such file or directory.
Can't open learn_chef_apache2: No such file or directory.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your $PATH, `type -a chef`. I'm guessing you have multiple `chef` executables installed, and the one from ChefDK is not first. You can move the `chef shell-init` to the bottom of your shellrc file.

Comment: This is the output: `root@chef-work:/home/ubuntu# type -a chef
chef is /usr/bin/chef
chef is /usr/games/chef
` What should I do?

Comment: Try running `/opt/chefdk/bin/chef --version` to see if ChefDK works on its own.